# Algorithm2e - write IfThenElse in one line

Tags: algorithm2e, ifthenelse

I have the following example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \lIf{$\max_{\mathcal{AV}} > \theta_5$}
        {
            \Return the tracklet with $\max_{\mathcal{AV}}$.
        }
        \lElse
        {
            \Return no speaker.
        }  
    \end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

however I do not want if and else be in two separate lines, but only in one.

Could anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `\lIfElse{<condition>}{<true>}{<false>}` to insert the `<false>` clause as part of `<true>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\lIfElse}[3]{\lIf{#1}{#2 \textbf{else}~#3}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{algorithm}
  \lIfElse{$a$}{True}{False}
  \lIfElse{$b$}{\Return True}{\Return False}
\end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is probably to do it manually:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[left=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \lIf{$\max_{\mathcal{AV}} > \theta_5$}
        {
            \Return the tracklet with $\max_{\mathcal{AV}}$. ; \textbf{else return} no speaker.
        }
    \end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I made the page a bit wider (with left margin reduced to 1cm) otherwise the text didn't fit on one line.

If you want to emulate the slightly larger space between *else* and *return* then you can do something like `\textbf{else\enspace return}`.